# Catching errors in text file lines, skipping and reporting

Tags: c++, string, whitespace, split

I have a text file that I need to read and each line is an IP, a URL, and finally a date, all separated by white spaces. I want to get each piece of information assigned to the appropriate variable of my Class Object "Visitor." I have an array of them in order to store them. My issue is when I try to go through the text file, and the lines...I keep getting the white spaces in between all of the text.

```
class Visitors{

public:
string IP;
string URL;
string dateAccessed;

};

int main(){

Visitors hits[N];

string filename, theLine;
ifstream infile;

cout << "Enter file name (with extension):" << flush;

while(true){

    string infilename;
    getline(cin, infilename);
    infile.open(infilename.c_str());
    if(infile) break;

    cout << "Invalid file. Please enter valid file name: " << flush;

}

cout << "\n";

while(!infile.eof()){

    getline(infile, theLine);

    istringstream iss(theLine);

    do{

        string ip;
        string url;
        string date;

        iss >> ip;
        iss >> url;
        iss >> date;

        if(ip != "\n"){

             cout << "The IP: " << ip << endl;

        }

        if(url != "\n"){

             cout << "The URL: " << url << endl;

        }

        if(date != "\n"){

            cout << "The DA: " << date << endl;

        }


    }while(iss);

}

return 0;

}
```

I tried using if-statements to grab all the strings that were just "new-lines" and ignore them but that didn't work so I am not entirely sure how to ignore them. I also want to add checks to see if any of the information is wrong (date isn't 2/2/4 characters long, missing www. in URL, etc.)

Here is some sample output to better show case my problem...

```
Enter file name (with extension):hits.txt

The IP: 192.168.1.101
The URL: www.cs.stonybrook.edu
The DA: 01/01/2013
The IP:
The URL:
The DA:
The IP: 192.168.1.101
The URL: www.cs.stonybrook.edu
The DA: 01/01/2013
The IP:
The URL:
The DA:
The IP: 123.112.15.151
The URL: www.cs.stonybrook.edu
The DA: 01/01/2013
```

EDIT: Okay so I have figured out how to go through each line, break it up and add the string accordingly to where it belongs in the class variables in the object array. Now the issue is I want to check each string of each line for errors(e.g. the dated is something impossible, or one of the numbers in the IP is 256 etc.). Upon discovery of that error I want to skip to the next line, do the same checks and if everything works out, it will initialize the class variables in the proper position in the array. Here is my code to get an idea of what I am trying to do...

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

#define N 50

using namespace std;

class Visitors{

public:
string IP;
string URL;
string dateAccessed;

};

int main(){

Visitors hits[N];

string infilename, filename, ip, url, date;
ifstream infile;

int i = 0;

cout << "Enter file name (with extension):" << flush;

while(true){

    infilename = "";
    getline(cin, infilename);
    infile.open(infilename.c_str());
    if(infile) break;

    cout << "Invalid file. Please enter valid file name: " << flush;

}

cout << "Loading " << infilename << "..." << endl;;
cout << "\n";

while(infile.good()){

    string line;
    getline(infile, line);
    stringstream ss(line);

    if(ss >> ip >> url >> date){

        cout << "The IP: " << ip << endl;
        hits[i].IP = ip;

        cout << "The URL: " << url << endl;
        hits[i].URL = url;

        cout << "The DA: " << date << endl;
        hits[i].dateAccessed = date;

        i++;

    }

    else{

        cerr << "error" << std::endl;

    }

    /*

    if(ip.length() > 15 || ip.length() < 7){

        cout << "Found a record with an invalid IP format (not XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX)...ignoring entry";

    }

    //if(any of the numbers in the IP address are great then 255)
        //INVALID IP...IGNORE ENTRY

    else{

        cout << "The IP: " << ip << endl;
        hits[i].IP = ip;

    }

    //if(url doesnt start with www. or doesnt end with .xxx)
        //INVALID URL...IGNORE ENTRY

    else{

        cout << "The URL: " << url << endl;
        hits[i].URL = url;

    }

    //if(date.length != 10)
        //INVALID DATE FORMAT...IGNORE ENTRY

    //if(first 2 numbers in date arent between 01 and 12
         //OR if second 2 numbers arent between 01 and 31 depending on month OR etc.)
         //INVALID....IGNORE ENTRY

    else{

        cout << "The DA: " << date << endl;
        hits[i].dateAccessed = date;

    }

    i++;*/

}

return 0;

}
```

It obviously isn't organized or put together how it would actually be in the program but it is the general idea of what I am looking to accomplish. My biggest problem is how to skip a line in the file without disturbing say my position in my array or if all of the lines have errors it catches every single one.

Comment: Why the inner loop? Can you have more entries in a single line?

Comment: No, one entry per line. I did it in hopes of like going through the list and then going through the lines as they get cut up into sub-strings and then getting each one and assigning them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do not need the stringstream, and the inner loop:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
int main(){
    std::string filename, theLine;
    std::ifstream infile;
    std::cout << "Enter file name (with extension):" << std::flush;
    while(true){
        std::string infilename;
        getline(std::cin, infilename);
        infile.open(infilename.c_str());
        if(infile) break;
        std::cout << "Invalid file. Please enter valid file name: " 
            << std::flush;
    }

    std::cout << "\n";
    std::string ip, url, date;
    while(infile.good()) {
        std::string line;
        getline(infile, line);
        std::stringstream ss(line);
        if (ss >> ip >> url >> date) {
            std::cout << "The IP: " << ip << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The URL: " << url << std::endl;
            std::cout << "The DA: " << date << std::endl;
        } else {
            std::cerr << "error" << std::endl;
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The inner loop you had tries to repeatedly parse the same line without reading a new line from the file.

Comment: How could I skip that line and go to the next set if errors are found?

Comment: @Sherifftwinkie, updated the answer. For this, you indeed need the stringstream :)

Comment: What about displaying error specific messages and swapping lines but not array positions when adding the data to the class variables of my class objects array. I'll update my OP in moments to better explain my intentions.

Comment: I've updated my OP with my intentions if you would like to take a look. Thank you for your help so far, really appreciate it.

Comment: change `if (ss >> ip >> url >> date)` to `if ( (ss >> ip >> url >> date) && isValidIP(ip) && isValidURL(url) && isValidDate(date) )` and implement these validation functions. That should be enough.

Answer (score 1):

```
cout << "Enter file name (with extension):" << flush;

string infilename;
getline(cin, infilename);
infile.open(infilename.c_str());

// You don't need to loop here. You can just exit the program. 
// But this is optional.
if(!infile) {
   cout << "Invalid file. Please enter valid file name: " << endl;
   exit(1);
}

cout << endl;

int line_nr = 1;
while(getline(infile, theLine)){
    istringstream iss(theLine);
    string ip;
    string url;
    string date;

    // A line is expected to have ip url date format. Otherwise it is error.
    if(iss >> ip >> url >> date)
        cout << "The IP: " << ip << endl;
        cout << "The URL: " << url << endl;
        cout << "The DA: " << date << endl;

     }

     else {
        cout << "Error reading data on line: " << line_nr << flush;
        break;
     }

     ++line_nr;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest solution (**in terms of how much code you have to change**) is to just compare with `""` instead of comaring with `"\n"`:

```
if (ip   != "") { cout << "The IP: "  << ip   << endl; }
if (url  != "") { cout << "The URL: " << url  << endl; }
if (date != "") { cout << "The DA: "  << date << endl; }
```

(Tested)

Comment: Oh man I had spaces and tried the new-line character. Didn't think to try that one. Thank you.